# Deleted exchange account still being auto suggested

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

I set up a new hire in our domain in exchange. When he arrived yesterday I discovered his name had been mispelled. I deleted his account and created a new account with proper spelling. The problem now is his old email address is being being suggested whenever anyone types in his first name. Users email the bad address get a bounce and create more help desk tickets. Is there a way to update exchange or purge the bad account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the name is in the client nickname cache. Have the users delete that entry from the nickname cache and that should take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

If it's being suggested by Outlook and as they type the name then the non-existent user pops up then that is a cache within Outlook. What they can do is use their arrow keys to highlight over the name and press the Delete key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias with the incorrect account that delivers to the correct account so the initial emails won't bounce.